# Как выполнить слияние объектов различных классов в один?

Tags: c#, классы, интерфейс, преобразование-типов

Имеется небольшая иерархия классов. Классы содержат как одинаковые свойства, так и свои, которые есть только у определённого класса. Стоит задача "слить" все классы в один, т.е. преобразовать различный типы к одному типу, который содержит все свойства классов. Скорее всего код покажет лучше, что требуется:

```
public interface ILetter {
    string A { get; set; }
    string B { get; set; }
    string C { get; set; }
}
public abstract class LetterBase : ILetter {
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}
public class First : LetterBase {
    public string D { get; set; }
    public string E { get; set; }
}
public class Second : LetterBase {
    public string F { get; set; }
    public string G { get; set; }
}
public class SuperPuper : LetterBase {
    public string D { get; set; }
    public string E { get; set; }
    public string F { get; set; }
    public string G { get; set; }
}
```

На данный момент перегружаю оператор явного преобразования типов:

```
public class SuperPuper : LetterBase {
    public string D { get; set; }
    public string E { get; set; }
    public string F { get; set; }
    public string G { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator SuperPuper(First first) {
        return new SuperPuper() {
            A = first.A,
            B = first.B,
            C = first.C,
            D = first.D,
            E = first.E
        };
    }
    public static explicit operator SuperPuper(Second second) {
        return new SuperPuper() {
            A = first.A,
            B = first.B,
            C = first.C,
            F = first.F,
            G = first.G
        };
    }
}

var first = new First { A = "a", B = "b", C = "c" };
var superPuper = (SuperPuper)first;
```

Но может быть имеется более лаконичный способ? При таком подходе при каждом изменении свойств классов нужно будет "синхронизировать" изменения в перегруженных операторах.
В комментариях предлагается рефлексия, но сие будет выполняться по ~500k раз и по нескольку раз в день и поэтому быстродействие приоритетней над сопровождением кода.

Comment: `"слить" все классы в один` - что это означает?

Comment: разовая задача или постоянно такое должно происходить?

Comment: @tym32167 имеются строго типизированные листы (List<First>, List<Second>) ~10 таблиц, в каждой ~50k записей, которые представляют таблицы MS Access. Необходимо из различных таблиц Access получить одну таблицу в MS SQL. Не совсем понял, что ты подразумеваешь под разовой задачей, но использоваться будет интенсивно.

Comment: то есть тебе нужен [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) для [маппинга](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) твоих сущностей в `SuperPuper`?

Comment: @tym32167 смотрел уже в его сторону... Если ничего не найду, то попробую. Так как он использует рефлексию, вполне возможно, что он не подойдёт. Думал найти нативное решение :(

Comment: [`Использует рефлексию` != `медленный`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38623228/312041)

Comment: @tym32167, это смотря с чем сравнивать :)

Comment: @Grundy всё относительно в нашем мире :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

есть только 2 пути преобразования одного класса в другой с присвоением одноименных параметров:

- ручная правка - нужно саппортить самому и обновлять при любом изменении вот это преобразование.
- рефлексия - нужно написать относительно много кода, который, к тому же, будет работать медленно.

  То есть берем имена всех параметров у this, перебираем их и ищем одноименные параметры у обьекта из которого мы должны тянуть данные. Если находим - присваиваем.

Чаще всего проще и быстрее пойти первым путем.

Answer (score 0):

Вот простенький мапер  с рефлексией

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var n = new Names() {N = "Udf", V = 2 };
            var m = new Vb();

            new Mapper().Map(n, m);

            Console.WriteLine($"{m.V}, {m.N}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

public class Mapper
    {
        public TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, TDestination destanation)
        {
            var fieldsSrc = source.GetType().GetProperties();
            var fieldsDesc = destanation.GetType().GetProperties();


            var mege = new List<PropertyInfo>();

            foreach (var field in fieldsSrc)
            {
                if (fieldsDesc.FirstOrDefault(v =>
                    v.Name == field.Name && v.PropertyType.Name == field.PropertyType.Name) != null)
                {
                    mege.Add(field);
                }
            }


            foreach (var field in fieldsDesc)
            {
                field.SetValue(destanation, mege.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Name == field.Name).GetValue(source));
            }


            return destanation;
        }
    }


    public class Names
    {
        public string N { get; set; }
        public int V { get; set; }
    }

    public class Vb
    {
        public string N { get; set; }
        public int V { get; set; }
    }
```